# Ralink - Wireless Weak / Poor Signal

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

I have switched from Windows to Ubuntu and after a few days i face a problem with wireless laptop connection, which has a slow signal and often is disconnecting. Anyone knows what to do to work properly? Thanks

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Feb 2017 11:15 EET +0200

Booted last: 04 Feb 2017 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-37-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 26 02:27:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:539a]
    DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink Ripple3 RT5390F_802.11 b/g/n 1x1 PCIe HMC
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1839]

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:183e]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0223 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:078c Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e8f:00a7 GreenAsia Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2800pci
mac80211              757760  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              581632  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
wmi                    16384  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5520  bytes 337697 (337.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5520  bytes 337697 (337.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e9a4:eb5a:8326:5de8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1223  bytes 909555 (909.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1300  bytes 206004 (206.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Clicknet-ECCF"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Clicknet-ECCF' [AN6]>   
          Bit Rate=57.8 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:8  Invalid misc:103   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1084     1  0 11:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.8.0-37-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:07:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Clicknet-ECCF
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       923a33a4-e555-4612-8091-91ec294fc517
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     57 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0,1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   923a33a4-e555-4612-8091-91ec294fc517 | Clicknet-ECCF
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   75a07422-8f64-4edd-a4f2-ca358f1be77f | RomTelecom-WEP-D09B
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.7/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1486285832
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.7
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e9a4:eb5a:8326:5de8/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID                 BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
DIRECT-C7-BRAVIA     <MAC 'DIRECT-C7-BRAVIA' [AN1]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
RomTelecom-WEP-D09B  <MAC 'RomTelecom-WEP-D09B' [AN2]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WEP        no        
RomTelecom-WPA-D09B  <MAC 'RomTelecom-WPA-D09B' [AN3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
Clicknet-4547        <MAC 'Clicknet-4547' [AN4]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
DIGI-49A6            <MAC 'DIGI-49A6' [AN5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Clicknet-ECCF        <MAC 'Clicknet-ECCF' [AN6]>  Infra  2     2417 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA2       yes     * 
WestMeck             <MAC 'WestMeck' [AN7]>  Infra  10    2457 MHz  54 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
HUAWEI-8hbv          <MAC 'HUAWEI-8hbv' [AN8]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
HUAWEI-Hx83          <MAC 'HUAWEI-Hx83' [AN9]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Clicknet-2875        <MAC 'Clicknet-2875' [AN10]>  Infra  4     2427 MHz  54 Mbit/s  19      ▂___  WPA2       no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/RomTelecom-WEP-D09B]] (600 root)
[connection] id=RomTelecom-WEP-D09B | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=RomTelecom-WEP-D09B
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Clicknet-ECCF]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Clicknet-ECCF | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Clicknet-ECCF
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Bucharest (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eno1      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2860.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     4D2CAAE95D28B3DF4F72A52
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2800mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2800 MMIO library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     DBE617B0243C0FEB62786D4
depends:        rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     7092408A4EF1A70FC0C7538
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 pci library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     D84965563CC7530CFFD2269
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 mmio library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     02CA9DA77FC2C7FCCC58176
depends:        rt2x00lib
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     CF930122B7900096FC259FA
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     C63473656FCDBBDA56E12DA
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-37-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     5F9AB87008B83E8D5117A0B
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800pci]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: Y
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf]
options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   22.186855] rt2800pci 0000:07:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   39.935790] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   39.935823] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2860.bin'
[   40.506250] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.40
[   40.662135] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   44.170695] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'Clicknet-ECCF' [AN6]>
[   44.194590] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'Clicknet-ECCF' [AN6]> (try 1/3)
[   44.196099] wlo1: authenticated
[   44.197627] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'Clicknet-ECCF' [AN6]> (try 1/3)
[   44.201041] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'Clicknet-ECCF' [AN6]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   44.201128] wlo1: associated
[   44.201141] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[   45.272011] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=63 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=28 
[   45.521957] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=64 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=28 
[   45.771992] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=107 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=28 
[   46.522065] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:e9a4:eb5a:8326:5de8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:0003 LEN=68 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=978145 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=28  (repeated 3 times)
[  110.071296] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush (repeated 3 times)
[  253.898980] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=53 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=10979 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=33 
[  253.899104] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=10980 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=40 
[  253.899139] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=10981 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=36 
[  254.026796] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=53 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=10994 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=33 
[  254.026890] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=10995 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=36 
[  254.026954] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=10996 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=40 
[  254.276779] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=53 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=11030 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=33 
[  254.276849] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=11031 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=40 
[  254.276883] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.7 DST=224.0.0.252 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=11032 PROTO=UDP SPT=5355 DPT=5355 LEN=36 
[  255.784641] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush (repeated 13 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: you are connected to clicknet. your home network is clicknet ?

Comment: and besides , you r connected to the 2nd cicknet which has a low rssi

Comment: I am at home and i have a router. I connect wireless to Clicknet-ECCF  On Windows worked ok, tablet and phone work ok, but Ubuntu not. I am beginner with linux